# Ruby on rails 5 show all results depending on related table quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models, one is shop and the other is address. A shop has many addresses and an address belongs to a shop.

I want to select (search) by name and filter all the shops that match with the search word and separated for each address, e.g. `search param[:name]`.

```
def filter_shops
     @shops = Shop.where("name ILIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')",params[:name])
end
```

This action searches all the shops by the param name, but I want that if a shop has 2 or 3 addresses it has to be shown in the result 2-3 times.

Example (expected results):

```
params[:name] value is "sho"

[{name: "shopOne",
 address: {
     id: 1,
     direction: "av. jojojo 321"}

},{name: "shopOne",
     address: {
           id: 2,
        direction: "onother avenue "}},
 {name: "shopTwo",
     address: {
           id: 7,
           direction: "av. of other shop 333"}
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [JOIN](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) tables:

```
Shop.joins(:adresses).where("shops.name ILIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')", params[:name])
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to create an array from example, you can do it like this (using multiple methods for convenience):

```
def create_array
  addresses.map do |address|
    {
      name: address.shop.name,
      address: {
        id:        address.id,
        direction: address.direction
      }
    }
  end
end

def addresses
  Address.eager_load(:shop)
         .where("shops.name ILIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')", params[:name])
         .order(:shop_id)
end
```

Comment: i test your code the result is close but not want i need. the shop appear 2 -3 times so its good, but each one has an array of the addresses, Example. shopOne with 2 address, and the next object is the same, the shopOne with an array of the 2 addresses, but i need as i show in the example, any other idea?

Comment: each shop with one address and shown in result as many addresses it has